# How can I stop my grails domain class from creating a table in my database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to make a model class which wouldn't require tables creation but I still want to be able to use tags associated with domain classes used in views and hence dont want to create those classes in `src` folder. Is there a way to do that without generating custom tags?

Comment: Have you looked into command objects? They behave like domains but they are not persistent.

Answer (score 1):

The `mapWith` static property adds the ability to control if a domain class is being persisted.

**Example:**

```
class Airport {

    static mapWith = "none"

}
```

In above example the **Airport** class will **not be persisted to the database**.

Please check [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2017/02/grails-goodness-using-domain-classes.html) for example and [this](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapWith.html) for documentation.

Hope this will helps u.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your domain inside src/main/groovy and tables will not be created.

Or in some situations you can use the 'embedded' declaration inside your domain object's nested object.